# Light Area under Glass

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I have a scene with a glass floor and a cavity underneath the glass. I would like to be able to actually **see** the cavity instead of just black glass (which is black for some reason that I'm hoping you guys can figure out a workaround to).

[image]

[image]

**What is the workaround so that I can still have the slight darkening and reflections that come with glass, but also be able to see through relatively well?** I'm going for a steampunk piano with some circuitry under the floor (not yet fully modeled).

A .blend (minus *Image Textures* because they're huge) to play with:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your Light Paths set to 0 Bounces in the Render tab. Try changing all these settings back to their default. I did and this is how it rendered.

[image]

Comment: Ha, totally missed that. Thanks for catching my error!

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the enlightenment of the whole scene. For now you have only one source light, and it's a "point" - this is not a light for lightning surfaces (even if it have 1000000000 value - like you have...) Second, all the scene is in a dark box. Apply the array modifier that you have to this hexagon and move the faces that behind the camera - that will allow to point a light source on the scene from the face.

It's all about the lights. After that you can play with the glass shader to polish the look you want.

PS. And It's not a cavity... It's just a background of the scene...